Android notification title not showing < android 12
I am creating a straight-forward foreground service with notification. The title is not showing even I am setting it with setContentTitle() function.
Here is my code for creating the channel:
 private fun createNextPrayerNotificationChannel(): NotificationChannel {
    return NotificationChannel(
        Unique.NAME_NEXT_PRAYER_CHANNEL,
        getString(R.string.next_prayer_channel),
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    )
}

And here's my code for creating notification:
 return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Unique.NAME_NEXT_PRAYER_CHANNEL)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setCustomContentView(contentView)
        .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
        .build()

Where the content view is custom.

As you said, you have to use setContentTitle for showing a title. However you do not use that function in the code you are showing. Use it in the builder as the following:
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Unique.NAME_NEXT_PRAYER_CHANNEL)
    .setContentTitle("A title")
    …
    .build()


I know, I use it in my code but it's not working. I just posted without it. In android > 11, I don't have to set it it, the system sets the title for me but before than even with using setContentTitle("") it won't show a title.
